# How can I plot validation curves using the results from GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am training a model with GridSearchCV in order to find the best parameters

Code:

```
grid_params = {
   'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400],
   'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
   'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
}

gs = GridSearchCV(
    RandomForestClassifier(),
    grid_params,
    cv=2,
    verbose=1,
    n_jobs=-1
)

clf = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is a slow process, and after this, I print the confusion matrix, but I want to plot the validation curve to in order to check if there are overfitting for this I use the following code:

```
train_scores, valid_scores = validation_curve(clf.best_estimator_, X, y)
```

The problem is that I need to set `param_name`, `param_range`, but I don't want to train again, because it is a too slow process.

Another choice is to use `gs`, instead of `clf.best_estimator_`, but I need the `gs` trained, in order to get another information.

How can I plot the validation curve, and keep the `gs` trainer, without train two times?

Comment: [Plotting Validation Curves](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html)

Comment: Why can't you leverage the `clf.cv_results_` attribute of the grid search object?

Comment: https://github.com/ray-project/tune-sklearn - might be helpful if you're running into slow gridsearchcv

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `cv_results_` attribute of `GridSearchCV` and get the results for each combination of hyperparameters. `Validation Curve` is meant to depict the impact of single parameter in training and cross validation scores.

Since fine tuning is done for multiple parameters in `GridSearchCV`, multiple plots are required to vizualise the impact of each parameter. Point to note is that the other parameter's impact has to be averaged out. This can be achieved by doing `groupby` on each parameter separately.

For mean train and test - the mean of means would work out, but for standard deviation we have to use [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance#Pooled_standard_deviation) because std deviations for each combination in Cross validation is almost constant.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,  
                           n_features=100, n_informative=2,
                           class_sep=0.1,random_state=7)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

grid_params = {
   'n_estimators': [10, 20],
   'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2'],
   'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
   'max_depth': [2, 5,]
}

cv = 5
gs = GridSearchCV(
    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42),
    grid_params,
    cv=cv,
    verbose=1,
    n_jobs=-1, 
    return_train_score=True # set this for train score
)

gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

import pandas  as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(gs.cv_results_)
results = ['mean_test_score',
           'mean_train_score',
           'std_test_score', 
           'std_train_score']

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance#Pooled_standard_deviation
def pooled_var(stds):
    n = cv # size of each group
    return np.sqrt(sum((n-1)*(stds**2))/ len(stds)*(n-1))


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(grid_params), 
                         figsize = (5*len(grid_params), 7),
                         sharey='row')
axes[0].set_ylabel("Score", fontsize=25)
lw = 2

for idx, (param_name, param_range) in enumerate(grid_params.items()):
    grouped_df = df.groupby(f'param_{param_name}')[results]\
        .agg({'mean_train_score': 'mean',
              'mean_test_score': 'mean',
              'std_train_score': pooled_var,
              'std_test_score': pooled_var})

    previous_group = df.groupby(f'param_{param_name}')[results]
    axes[idx].set_xlabel(param_name, fontsize=30)
    axes[idx].set_ylim(0.0, 1.1)
    axes[idx].plot(param_range, 
                grouped_df['mean_train_score'],
                label="Training score",
                color="darkorange",
                lw=lw)
    axes[idx].fill_between(param_range,
                grouped_df['mean_train_score'] - grouped_df['std_train_score'],
                grouped_df['mean_train_score'] + grouped_df['std_train_score'],
                alpha=0.2,
                color="darkorange",
                lw=lw)
    axes[idx].plot(param_range,
                grouped_df['mean_test_score'],
                label="Cross-validation score",
                color="navy",
                lw=lw)
    axes[idx].fill_between(param_range,
                    grouped_df['mean_test_score'] - grouped_df['std_test_score'],
                    grouped_df['mean_test_score'] + grouped_df['std_test_score'],
                    alpha=0.2,
                    color="navy",
                    lw=lw)

handles, labels = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.suptitle('Validation curves', fontsize=40)
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc=8, ncol=2, fontsize=20)

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25, top=0.85)  
plt.show()
```

[image: validation curve]

Note: line plots are not the right one for parameters with string values like `criterion`, you could modify it to be bar plots with error bars.

Comment: thank you for this. what are the bands around the lines? sometimes i get them sometimes i don't

Comment: this code throws `'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable` if there is only one parameter being optimized

Comment: remove the indexing of `axes` var ( `axes[0]` -> `axes`)

Comment: How was n = 5 determined within `pooled_var()` please? I can see the comment re: group size and am unsure how this was determined.

Comment: It should take the value given for param `cv`. In the given example cv is 5.

Answer (score 5):

Finnaly I used this code:

```
grid_params = {
   'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400],
   'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
   'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
   # 'bootstrap': [True]
}

gs = GridSearchCV(
    RandomForestClassifier(),
    grid_params,
    cv=10,
    verbose=1,
    n_jobs=-1,
    return_train_score=True,
    scoring='f1_micro'
)

clf = gs.fit(X, y)

test_scores = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
train_scores = clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score'] 

plt.plot(test_scores, label='test')
plt.plot(train_scores, label='train')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```